# Weekly newsletter alert on Blog library shows pending entries

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-online, alert, office-365, blog

We have setup an alert on our internal blog that sends an email once a week with all the new blog posts, as follows:

[image]

The problem is that it sends both Approved and Pending blog posts.

Is there a way to solve that and only send Approved blog posts?

We are on Office 365 - Sharepoint 2010

Answer (score 2):

When the users who get the pending posts in the email go to the blog can they see the pending posts?

You may be able to fix it by making pending posts not visible to everyone. Then the email should also not show the pending posts.